# the_excerpt - want to modify password protected output

Tags: excerpt

I'm looking to modify the output of the_excerpt when there isn't an excerpt specified and the post is password protected. I already can modify the password protected form to whatever I want, but the_excerpt is outputting "There is no excerpt because this is a protected post.".

The code for this lies in wp-includes/post-template.php:

```
function get_the_excerpt( $deprecated = '' ) {
    if ( !empty( $deprecated ) )
        _deprecated_argument( __FUNCTION__, '2.3' );

    global $post;
    $output = $post->post_excerpt;
    if ( post_password_required($post) ) {
        $output = __('There is no excerpt because this is a protected post.');
        return $output;
    }

    return apply_filters('get_the_excerpt', $output);
}
```

An easy solution would be to simply change the code in there and move on, but as well all know, changing core files deserves more than a slap across the face! Can anyone help me figure out how to modify this code in my functions.php file?

Thanks!

**EDIT**: Here's the code I tried out, but it isn't working :(

```
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'improved_get_the_excerpt');
function improved_get_the_excerpt( $deprecated = '' ) {
    if ( !empty( $deprecated ) )
        _deprecated_argument( __FUNCTION__, '2.3' );

    global $post;
    $output = $post->post_excerpt;
    if ( post_password_required($post) ) {
        $output = __('This is some test content.');
        return $output;
    }
}
```

I'm completely new to the concept of filters, actions, hooks, etc so please bear with me! I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple way would be to check output in template (or small wrapper):

```
$excerpt = get_the_excerpt();

if( 'There is no excerpt because this is a protected post.' == $excerpt ) {

    // stuff
}
else {

    echo $excerpt;
}
```

Another way would be to use `gettext` filter (which is used inside `__()`) to catch and modify that phrase.

Comment: +1 for the method I tried first! I had almost the exact same code when I first tried to tackle this problem, but it doesn't seem like the most efficient way. I'm actually trying to do it the way I asked in my question so that I am forced to learn something new about WordPress :) specifically actions, filters, hooks, and general plugin development processes.

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to look into add_filter().

Here's the codex link to it: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter

Here's another Article I refer to from time to time: http://otto42.com/ak

-Cheers

Edit: [Passing a parameter to filter and action functions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45901/passing-a-parameter-to-filter-and-action-functions)

Comment: +1 for pointing me to the API, which I hadn't come across. On a related note, doesn't it seem shockingly incomplete? Also, please see my edit - I still can't quite get it to work!

Answer (score 1):

`get_the_excerpt()` is not a pluggable function, so you cannot overwrite it by simply naming a function the same as it. Because there is no hook between checking the protected status and `return`ing the text that the excerpt cannot be displayed, you will have to do the filtering once `the_excerpt()` has been gotten using a method as suggested by @Rarst in his solution.

There is a (hacky) way to get around this, you can use the i18n features to replace the text that is output by the function, but this is a bad solution as it uses the i18n features in a way that they are wholly not intended to be used.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the advice, I learn something new from this site every day!