# How to Pass External Variables to Filters/Actions

Tags: filters, variables

I find myself needing to pass custom data to a filter provided by a 3rd party plugin. All of the ways I've seen to do this are really complicated and hard to wrap my head around.

Take this example:

```
$score = 42; //Some crazy calculation I don't want to repeat.

function add_score_to_title($title) {
    return 'Quiz Results (' . $score . '/') - ' . $title;
}

add_filter( 'aioseop_title_single', 'add_score_to_title');
```

How can I pass the `$score` variable to `add_score_to_title()`?

What I ended up doing was adding my variable onto the global `$wp` object. So you end up with this:

```
global $wp;
$score = 42; //Some crazy calculation I don't want to repeat.
$wp->some_random_name_for_score = $score;

function add_score_to_title($title) {
    global $wp;
    $score = $wp->some_random_name_for_score;
    return 'Quiz Results (' . $score . '/') - ' . $title;
}

add_filter( 'aioseop_title_single', 'add_score_to_title');
```

Dirty? Maybe. Simple? Yup! Any downsides to this technique? Please discuss.

**UPDATE**
Here is the complete code in question -> http://pastebin.com/fkSXY04m

Comment: Simply do your "crazy calculation" inside that function...

Comment: It's probably hard to understand from my simplified example. The $score variable is used throughout that template. I want to calculate it once and pass that value to the function which is a callback for a filter for changing the page title. This filter is used in the All In One SEO Pack. Running the calculation multiple times is not desired.

Comment: Then you should post more code if you want to get a solution that doesn't involve introducing global state (which should  never be needed).

Comment: Here is the complete code in a template file. `$score` is calculated by looping over an array of things and incrementing a variable.

http://pastebin.com/fkSXY04m

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing a parameter to filter and action functions](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45901/passing-a-parameter-to-filter-and-action-functions)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have at least two options:

1. Globalize the desired variable, and then reference it inside the callback
2. Wrap the score calculation logic with a function, then reference it inside the callback

#### Globalize the Variable

```
<?php
global $score;
$score = 42; //Some crazy calculation I don't want to repeat.

function add_score_to_title($title) {
    global $score;
    return 'Quiz Results (' . $score . '/') - ' . $title;
}

add_filter( 'aioseop_title_single', 'add_score_to_title');
?>
```

#### Wrap the Score Calculation

If you only ever need the score calculation *inside* the filter, pull the logic into the callback itself:

```
<?php
function add_score_to_title($title) {
    $score = 0;
    $questions = get_quiz_result_questions();
    $total_questions = 0;
    foreach( $questions as $question ) {
        $order = $question->order;

        if( $order >= 100 ) {
            break;
    }

    if( $question->correct == $_POST['Q'][$order] ) {
        $score++;
    }
    $total_questions++;

    return 'Quiz Results (' . $score . '/') - ' . $title;
}

add_filter( 'aioseop_title_single', 'add_score_to_title');
?>
```

Better yet, you could wrap your score calculation in a function of its own, and then call that function inside your callback:

```
<?php
function wpse48677_get_score() {
    $score = 0;
    $questions = get_quiz_result_questions();
    $total_questions = 0;
    foreach( $questions as $question ) {
    $order = $question->order;

    if( $order >= 100 ) {
        break;
    }

    if( $question->correct == $_POST['Q'][$order] ) {
        $score++;
    }
    $total_questions++;
    $output['score'] = $score;
    $output['total_questions'] = $total_questions;

    return $output;
}

function add_score_to_title($title) {

    $score_results = wpse48677_get_score();

    $score = $score_results['score'];

    return 'Quiz Results (' . $score . '/') - ' . $title;
}

add_filter( 'aioseop_title_single', 'add_score_to_title');
?>
```

If you find you have problems referencing the `$_POST` object, you can also register your query variable and then use `get_query_var()` internally to get data:

```
function add_score_query_vars( $query_vars ) {
    $query_vars[] = 'Q';

    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_score_query_vars' );
```

With this in place, `$_POST['Q']` can be replaced with `get_query_var('Q')`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the number of arguments passed to the function by apply_filters...

Comment: Tried method #1 you mention of globalizing the variable. It doesn't work. Accepted args paramter doesn't help me either since I have no control over what variables are passed to the callback function.

Comment: Sorry you were right. I calculated `$score` first and then globalized it. No wonder it wasn't working. Thank you!

Comment: -1. First option exposes a variable in the global state, 2nd option doesn't work...

Comment: Updated to reflect I was in err on the second option. But what's wrong with exposing a global variable? It's certainly better than using an anonymous function in a callback. :)

Comment: No, it's not. And [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166087/php-global-in-functions) are a few reasons why you should avoid this practice. Maybe it's ok for his specific case, but what if someone actually builds a public plugin using your solution?

Comment: "*Globals are evil*"? *Really*? Then the entire WordPress code had better be written, since [it relies on quite a few global variables](http://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables).

Comment: Exactly. This is one of the reasons why WP's base code is one of the worst on the web. Anyway, WP has an excuse - the required compatibility with plugins designed for older versions. You don't :)

Comment: Yeah... I'm gonna leave that one alone. Thanks for pointing out the issue with the second option; I've removed it from the question. I stand by the acceptability of using global variables. If I knew how the Plugin output was generated or returned, I could probably offer a better solution.

Comment: See updated answer; having looked at the Pastebin, I've offered two methods that I would prefer to using a global variable.

Comment: Better, but he wants the "score" to be accessible later in the script, without re-calculating it, so the use of a "static" variable makes sense here.

Comment: Using a function to calculate score: couldn't the calculation be stored in object cache?

Comment: fall of 2015 and WP is still relying on **evil** global variables. The excuse has gotten too old. And +1 for the globalizing suggestion. In my case the callback needed to access the `$user` which I needed to _globalize_ since my `apply_filters` call was being initiated from inside a function.

Comment: These Globals are evil people need to chill. I like this answer quite a bit. The OP asked how passing variables between functions could be done. This answer explains *several* ways to do that. Starts w/ globals, which *are* best to avoid, but still are *a thing that exists* and solves the problem at hand. Then the answer proceeds to explain several better options that might work in some circumstances.

Answer (score 4):

```
function add_score_to_title($title = false) {
  static $score = false;

  if($score === false){
    // do calc
  }

  // plugin call (filter)   
  if($title !== false)
    return 'Quiz Results (' . $score . ') - ' . $title;

  // your call
  return $score;
}
```

Call the function anywhere in your script to get the score, it will only be calculated once.

Another way, using [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php):

```
// do the calc
$score = 'xxx';

add_filter('aioseop_title_single', function($title) use($score){
  return 'Quiz Results (' . $score . ') - ' . $title;  
});
```

Comment: Anonymous functions should not be used in `add_filter()` or `add_action()` calls. They cannot be removed via `remove_function()`.

Comment: You mean remove_filter, which is mainly used to remove built-in filters, not filters added by plugins/themes...

Comment: Yes; sorry: `remove_filter()` and `remove_action()`. And there's no reason that Plugin/Theme filters shouldn't reasonably be able to be removed: override Plugin stylesheet enqueues, Child Themes, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The following example sees the variable `$my_calculation` in the global scope, however from within our local function we need to declare `global $my_calculation` in order to access the variable in the global scope.

```
<?php 

    $my_calculation = 'result!';

    function my_function() {

        global $my_calculation;
        return $my_calculation;

    }

    add_filter( 'function_something_here', 'my_function');   

?>
```

This is just one way to go about it and it appears to be neat. Would this work for you?

Comment: How is this any different from what he already has?

Comment: Once less declaration of "global". Look at his second example, he declares gloabl $wp twice!

Comment: It also doesn't work. This is the first thing I tried.

Comment: Are you able to `print` or `echo` your result to ensure that your function is indeed working prior to passing it to the filter?

Comment: Oops! Globalizing `$score` does indeed work. I goofed and set `$score` first then globalized which clearly doesn't work. Doing it the proper way by globalizing `$score` first then giving it a value works as expected. Thanks all.

Comment: That's what I was about to say next after looking at your script, was a little backwards ;) Have fun!