# Why won't the action hook wp_head accept parameters?

Tags: templates, variables, wp-head, parameter

I'm working on a plugin that adds scripting to the head using

```
add_action('wp_head',..);
```

I have to pass a variable to the function to get my desired result. To test this I'm simple "echoing" out the variable to be sure it's passing.

I'm calling the function within a page template. The variable is echoed in the body but not the head:

```
function add_brand_style($newItem){
    global $newItem;
    echo 'item:'.$newItem;
}
add_action('wp_head','add_brand_style');
```

the head i get "item:' and in the body I get something like "item:dog".

Comment: You are off ot a bad start by adding scripts using wp_head. You should enqueue scripts properly: [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) [tut](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-ins-and-outs-of-the-enqueue-script-for-wordpress-themes-and-plugins/)

Comment: Not to mention wp_head shouldn't take in parameters per the codex.

Comment: Possibly you should also look into localizing scripts: [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script)

Comment: Have you read [Passing a parameter to filter and action functions](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45901/passing-a-parameter-to-filter-and-action-functions)?

Comment: @vancoder - If there is a better way to archive what the user is asking, why not write up an answer explaining the methods and providing examples of what you're suggesting(what good is saying "use x not y" without providing examples of how to do so).

Comment: @t31os The good is that I'm pointing him in the right direction, as I don't have time to rewrite his code for him. This is why I added a comment, and not an answer. My comment seems somewhat more helpful than your own.

Comment: I think you should give more details on what you're trying to achieve. Where does `$newItem` coming from? Different enqueueing techniques are possible with conditional tags. The issue is not *"why does the hook not accept external parameters"*, but "how can this be overcome in my specific use case". toschos' link is priceless, favorited!

Comment: I agree with @brasofilo that the way to make progress on this is to explain what you want to accomplish. I think there may be an [x/y problem](https://www.google.com/search?q=x%2Fy+problem) here.

Comment: Might be worth the read: [Difference Between Filter and Action Hooks?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1008/22534)

Answer (score 1):

Well, for me the problem, was including during the post content it would not work, but if i did included in the top of the page template model i created, then it would work if i used something like this: VALID FOR PHP 5.3+

```
$array = array("keywords" => "keywords here", "description" => "desc here");
add_action( 'wp_head', function() use ( $array ) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if ($key == "description") { echo "your meta here"; }
    }
}, 1 );
```