# Add Filter - Pass Variable (PHP < 5.3)

Tags: filters, excerpt

When using Anonymous Functions in PHP < 5.3 I get this error:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION`

This is especially troublesome for add_filters. For instance, if I want to make a filter for a custom excerpt

**The Function**

```
function custom_excerpt($new_length = 20, $new_more = '...', $strip = false) {
    add_filter('excerpt_length', function () use ($new_length) {
        return $new_length;
    }, 999);
    add_filter('excerpt_more', function () use ($new_more) {
        return $new_more;
    });
    $output = get_the_excerpt();
    $output = apply_filters('wptexturize', $output);
    $output = apply_filters('convert_chars', $output);
    if(!$strip)
        $output = '<p>' . $output . '</p>';
    echo $output;
}
```

The function above accepts 3 parameters, lenth, read more, strip. You pass this function a new length such as '30' and it will give me an post excerpt of 30 words. The read more will replace the default `[...]` with the functions default `...`. The point of this is to use `the_excerpt()` and change the amount of words and remove the `[...]`

My question now is how can I pass my `$new_length` variable to this filter in PHP < 5.3?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? Can you please **edit your question** to better explain what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412032/php-anonymous-function-causes-syntax-error-on-some-installations

Comment: @s_ha_dum - that makes sense, so it's the PHP version I'm using. The link you suggested says to use a separate function, but with `add_filter` can I do this while still passing my `$new_length`?

Comment: "*...but with add_filter can I do this while still passing my $new_length?*" - this would make a fantastic question for WPSE, and one even better than what you have currently. Would you mind **editing your question** accordingly?

Comment: @ChipBennett I wasn't sure what to title it, feel free to throw a better title in there. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction guys!

Comment: [Passing a parameter to filter and action functions](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45901/passing-a-parameter-to-filter-and-action-functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like the second option, but I think it would be overkill. Instead, just write your own custom analog to [`wp_trim_excerpt()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_excerpt) (the function that applies the `excerpt_length` and `excerpt_more` filters to the excerpt), like so:

```
function custom_excerpt( $new_length = 20, $new_more = '...', $strip = false ) {
    // Start with the content
    $text = get_the_content('');

    // Do stuff to it
    $text = strip_shortcodes( $text );
    $text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
    $text = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $text);

    // Use custom values
    $excerpt_length = $new_length;
    $excerpt_more = $new_more;
    $text = wp_trim_words( $text, $excerpt_length, $excerpt_more );

    // Strip?
    if ( ! $strip ) {
        $text = '<p>' . $text . '</p>';
    }

    // Output
    echo $text;
}
```

Overkill method:

```
function custom_excerpt( $new_length = 20, $new_more = '...', $strip = false ) {
    // Excerpt length
    add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
    function custom_excerpt_length( $new_length ) {
        return $new_length;
    }

    // Excerpt More
    add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'custom_excerpt_more' );
    function custom_excerpt_more( $new_more ) {
        return $new_more;
    }

    // Output
    $output = get_the_excerpt();
    $output = apply_filters('wptexturize', $output);
    $output = apply_filters('convert_chars', $output);
    if(!$strip)
        $output = '<p>' . $output . '</p>';
    echo $output;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Why do you consider the 2nd method overkill - it looks like it's doing less to achieve the same thing.

Comment: I'm not really a fan of nested function declarations. But if it works for you, it's a viable option. :)