# Can I pass parameters to the add_shortcode() function?

Tags: shortcode, parameter

As the title states, I need to pass at least one parameter, maybe more, to the [`add_shortcode()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/) function. In other words, those parameters I am passing will be used in the callback function of `add_shortcode()`. How can I do that?

Please note, those have NOTHING to do with the following structure `[shortcode 1 2 3]` where `1`, `2`, and `3` are the parameters passed by the user. In my case, the parameters are for programming purposes only and should not be the user's responsibility.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [closure](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php) for that together with the `use` keyword. Simple example:

```
$dynamic_value = 4;

add_shortcode( 'shortcodename', 
    function( $attributes, $content, $shortcode_name ) use $dynamic_value 
    {
        return $dynamic_value;
    }
);
```

See also [Passing a parameter to filter and action functions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/45920/73).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an array of attributes ($atts) in the callback function that will run whenever you run add_shortcode().

notice the `$user_defined_attributes` in the following example:

```
add_shortcode( 'faq', 'process_the_faq_shortcode' );
/**
 * Process the FAQ Shortcode to build a list of FAQs.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 *
 * @param array|string $user_defined_attributes User defined attributes for this shortcode instance
 * @param string|null $content Content between the opening and closing shortcode elements
 * @param string $shortcode_name Name of the shortcode
 *
 * @return string
 */
function process_the_faq_shortcode( $user_defined_attributes, $content, $shortcode_name ) {
    $attributes = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'number_of_faqs' => 10,
            'class'          => '',
        ),
        $user_defined_attributes,
        $shortcode_name
    );

    // do the processing

    // Call the view file, capture it into the output buffer, and then return it.
    ob_start();
    include( __DIR__ . '/views/faq-shortcode.php' );
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

reference: [hellofromtonya](https://gist.github.com/hellofromtonya/ced966dd791820c50aa8010dd582d222)

Comment: Thanks @GeorgeP, however, you are not showing how I pass the `$user_defined_attributes` parameter, can you show in an example please? I believe `$user_defined_attributes` are passed as shortcode params, and this is NOT what I want, as I explained in my question above.